# question about transitive relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

can any one explain these answer

1)we have set $X={1,2,3,4}$,the relation set is given as

$R={(1,2),(3,4)}$

it is transitive

also, $r={(4,4)} $

it is transitive

why the sets R,r have achieved the property of transitive ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitive relation:
For all $a,b,c \in R \times R$: 
$$ aRb \land bRc \space \implies aRc$$
Meaning: if $a$ relates to $b$ and $b$ relates to $c$, transitivity demands that $a$ relates to $c$ as well.

${(1,2)(3,4)}$ is transitive because it is not given the opportunity not to be :-). Notice that the 2nd element of each couple never appears as a 1st element. So the **IF** of transitivity is always false, and hence the implication is always true, and we have a transitive relation!

$r$ satisfies the above: $4R4$ and $4R4$ indeed, but we also have $4R4$. :-P

$R \cup r$ indeed is transitive. check it!

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a set is transitive if (and only if) whenever we take two ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ from the relation, we are guaranteed that $(x,z)$ is also in the relation.

Both the examples that you gave satisfy that simply because if we take $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ then it is necessarily the case that $(x,y)=(y,z)$ and therefore $x=y=z$, so $(x,z)$ is also in the relation.

Note that nowhere we request that $x\neq y$ and $y\neq z$ in the definition.